# C++ argument of type "void(*)(int wall) is incompatible with parameter of type "int"

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I'm pretty new to C++, I'm not sure how to correct the error. This is part of my code, the error appears in my main function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function declaration
void gallons(int wall);
void hours(int gallons);
void costPaint(int gallons, int pricePaint);
void laborCharges(int hours);
void totalCost(int costPaint, int laborCharges);

 // Function definition
 void gallons(int wall)
 {
   int gallons;

   gallons = wall / 112;

   cout << "Number of gallons of paint required: " << gallons << endl;

    }

  // Function definition
  void hours(int gallons)
  {
    int hours;

    hours = gallons * 8;

    cout << "Hours of labor required: " << hours << endl;


  }

  // Function definition
  void costPaint(int gallons, int pricePaint)
  {
    int costPaint;

    costPaint = gallons * pricePaint;

    cout << "The cost of paint: " << costPaint << endl;
  }

  // Function definition
     void laborCharges(int hours)
  {
    int laborCharges;

    laborCharges = hours * 35;

     cout << "The labor charge: " << laborCharges << endl;
   }

  // Funtion definition
  void totalCost(int costPaint, int laborCharges)
   {
      int totalCost;

      totalCost = costPaint + laborCharges;

      cout << "The total cost of the job: " << totalCost << endl;
    }

    // The main method
    int main()
    {
    int wall;
    int pricePaint;

    cout << "Enter square feet of wall: ";
    cin >> wall;

    cout << "Enter price of paint per gallon: ";
    cin >> pricePaint;

    gallons(wall);

    hours(gallons); // here's where the error is

    costPaint(gallons, pricePaint); // here's where the error is

    laborCharges(hours); // here's where the error is 

    return 0;

        }
```

This is where I keep getting the error " C++ argument of type "void(*)(int wall) is incompatible with parameter of type "int" " I get it hours, costPaint, and labor charges. If I can figure out how to fix the first one I can fix all three since its essentially the same issue.

Comment: `gallons(wall);` -- What is your intent with this line of code?

Comment: In `laborCharges(hours);`, what do you think `hours` means?

Comment: Where is your `gallons` function?

Comment: Is `gallons` a variable or a function?  The statement `gallons(wall)` indicates `gallons` is a function, however, `hours(gallons)` indicates that `gallons` is a variable.  To complicate matters, you don't have a variable declaration or function declaration for `gallons`.

Comment: You need to distinguish clearly between variables and functions. You've defined `hours` as both (you have a variable `int hours;` defined in side your function `void hours(int gallons)`, which it's illegal, but it's confusing and a bad idea). Do you want your `hours()` function to return a value? If so, you need to define it as something like `int hours(int gallons)`.

Comment: I changed my function name to getSomething and kept my variables same. It fixed that problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void hours(int gallons);

int gallons(int wall) 
{
    return wall * wall;
}

void hours(int gallons)

{
    int hours;

    hours = gallons * 8;

    cout << "Hours of labor required: " << hours << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int wall;
    int pricePaint;

    cout << "Enter square feet of wall: ";
    cin >> wall;

    cout << "Enter price of paint per gallon: ";
    cin >> pricePaint;

    hours(gallons(wall));

    return 0;

}
```

You may want this kind of code.

In your code, 'gallons' in the main function is treated as a function because 'gallons' is a function name.

But, You do not want to use a function as a argument, but rather a function's return value.

So you just need to fix the code like above.